# Check if path is on network

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In my app I have a dialog in which the user can select a database backup location.
I want to warn the user if the location he/she selected is "probably not secure".

I want to consider the following locations secure:

1. When selected folder is on a network
   (either by a mapped drive (`I:\Backup`) or UNC notation(`\\server2\backup`))
2. When selected folder is on a different physical disk than the database folder

How can I get this kind of info about a selected folder?
I know about the `DriveInfo` class, but it only handles drive letters, not UNC paths.

Comment: Hi Robbert! If one of the answers below provided a doable solution, could you please accept that one as the answer, just so this question no longer shows up as `unanswered`. Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

Take a look at the [PathIsNetworkPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773640(VS.85).aspx) function:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll")]
    private static extern bool PathIsNetworkPath(string pszPath);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(PathIsNetworkPath("i:\Backup"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a FYI: The function does not verify that the specified network resource exists, is currently accessible, or that the user has sufficient permissions to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `DirectoryInfo` object.  Open one on the selected path and you can check many things.  Perhaps you might want to fetch the `DirectorySecurity` and check if the path is locked down.

A proactive programmer might create a new folder for his/her application backup and create a strong ACL themselves...

Comment: I don't think that this is a good idea to add ACLs, because this adds more complexity and it's always better to keep it simple.

Comment: It's better to be secure by default.  If they're avoiding unc posts and storing locally. Ensuring a good ACL exists on the storage location is another layer.