# Why do these DLLs have two apparently identical entry points?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, dllimport

Today, working on some VB.NET code I had to access two external DLLs in order to use some methods. The help topics that I found told me to use the following external methods:

- **shlwapi.dll** → PathIsNetworkPath ([Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243569/check-if-path-is-on-network))
- **mpr.dll** → WNetAddConnection2 and WNetCancelConnection2 ([Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1197430/2837436))

However, when I tried to call these methods from my code, I got an error saying that the entry point did not exist. So I did some research and I found out that the DLLs in my operative System (Windows 7 enterprise 32 bits) do not include these methods exactly, but instead, I got:

- **PathIsNetworkPath** → PathIsNetworkPath**A** / PathIsNetworkPath**W**
- **WNetAddConnection2** → WNetAddConnection2**A** / WNetAddConnection2**W**
- **WNetCancelConnection2** → WNetCancelConnection2**A** / WNetCancelConnection2**W**

So, I tested their behaviour:
* Methods finishing with "A" work just as expected.
* Methods finishing with "W" do not work as expected, they raise errors or return wrong results (g.i. "false" when it should be "true").
And yet however, nobody in the help topics mentions having a similar problem.

So I did a little research and in the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2a) [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathisnetworkpatha) I found that the DLLs contain only the methods that finish with "A" and "W", and both of them, in the three cases that I use, the documentation pages are identical as far as I can see. As a matter of fact all along the page, they don't use the name of the method that ends with A/W but without it.

So my questions are: *why do I have methods "A" and "W" instead of the one without A/W in my DLLs? What's the difference between both of them? Why do methods "A" work for me while methods "W" don't?

Comment: The pinvoke marshaller already knows about this detail.  The CharSet property you use in the [DllImport] declaration matters, CharSet.Ansi (the default) selects the A version and the others select W.  All we really know is that your declaration is not correct, we can't see it.

Comment: I chose to reopen because the question is more about the Visual Basic side of things rather than merely the difference between A and W variants of WinAPI functions, @Damien.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Windows NT 4 / 2000 / XP, WinAPI functions come in ANSI (A) and Unicode (W) variants. See also [What is the difference between the `A` and `W` functions in the Win32 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424383/what-is-the-difference-between-the-a-and-w-functions-in-the-win32-api).

When using P/Invoke, there's a difference between C# and VB.NET. See [Specifying a Character Set on MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/specifying-a-character-set?view=netframework-4.7.2), specifically "String Marshaling and Name Matching" and "Specifying a Character Set in Visual Basic":

> When the DllImportAttribute.ExactSpelling field is true, as it is by default in Visual Basic 2005, platform invoke searches only for the name you specify. For example, if you specify MessageBox, platform invoke searches for MessageBox and fails when it cannot locate the exact spelling.

Given the default for the DllImportAttribute.CharSet field is "ANSI" for C# and VB.NET, the rules for Visual Basic determine that the runtime *doesn't* search for the **A** or **W** entry point, see [Docs: DllImportAttribute.ExactSpelling Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.exactspelling?view=netframework-4.7.2). This is for backwards compatibility with Visual Basic I guess.

So you have three options:

1. Explicitly specify the "W" entry point and CharSet.Unicode:

   ```
   <DllImport("shlwapi.dll", EntryPoint:="PathIsNetworkPathW", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
   Public Function PathIsNetworkPath(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)>pszPath As String) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)>Boolean
   End Function
   ```
2. Disable exact spelling, causing the runtime to search for the "A" entry point (given the default charset, when not specified, is ANSI):

   ```
   <DllImport("shlwapi.dll", EntryPoint:="PathIsNetworkPath", SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=False)> _
   Public Function PathIsNetworkPath(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)>pszPath As String) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)>Boolean
   End Function
   ```
3. Set the CharSet to Auto, implying a [platform-specific character set (Unicode for most OSes)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.charset?view=netframework-4.7.2) and ExactSpelling False:

   ```
   <DllImport("shlwapi.dll", EntryPoint:="PathIsNetworkPath", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
   Public Function PathIsNetworkPath(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)>pszPath As String) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)>Boolean
   End Function
   ```

I'd prefer option 3, as it eliminates useless (or even dangerous, as it might lead to data loss) Unicode -> ANSI -> Unicode conversion of the strings, and doesn't require you to explicitly specify the "W" variants of the functions.

Comment: Thank you @CodeCaster for your detailed response. I did search but I did not find the topic that you refer to at the start of your post, it gives me already some responses, but your answer is far more complete.